# pure virtual function calling

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

The first `printable(e)` is giving "entity" but for the next line, the program crashes. giving some characters. Let me know the error.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    virtual string getclassname() = 0;
};

class entity : public A
{
public:
    string getclassname() override
    {
        cout << "entity" << endl;
    }
};

class player : public entity
{
private:
    string m_name2;

public:
    player(const string& name2) // Creating a constructor
        :m_name2(name2) {}

    string getname()
    {
        return m_name2;
    }
public:
    string getclassname() override
    {
        cout << "player" << endl;
    }
};

void printable(A* en)
{
    cout << en->getclassname() << endl;
}

int main()
{
    entity* e = new entity();
    player* p = new player("bird");

    printable(e);
    printable(p);
}
```

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly by adopting an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and applying it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it.

Comment: Oops: `main.cpp:20:5: error: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Werror=return-type]`

Comment: @FredLarson Just saw that.

Comment: Also, it would be advisable to define a virtual destructor in `A`, although you aren't presently using polymorphic deletion.

Comment: @FredLarson How should I do that. Can you please elaborate on it.

Comment: `virtual ~A() = default;` should do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `getclassname()` function doesn't return anything even though it promises it does. This results in *undefined behaviour*. You should not print, but instead compose a string:

```
string getclassname() override
{
    return "player";
}
```

Comment: It worked, but does it should always have a "return".  Can't I use cout?
But why It is printing Entity and not the next one. Thanks

Comment: @AdupaVasista: "return" and "output" are different things. `cout` will output to the user's console. `return` will send the value to the calling code within the program.

Comment: @FredLarson. Thank you. Got it.

Comment: and why is the program crashing after printing Entity? Any idea. Thanks

Comment: @AdupaVasista Because that's one possible outcome of breaking the language rules like you did. You broke your program. If your book doesn't explain this, I'll eat my facemask

Comment: That's a question your debugger can answer. Turn on more compiler warnings, or even all of them to be sure you're not making obvious mistakes.

Comment: @tadman: To be fair, with a missing `return`, that's going to be rather difficult to diagnose in a debugger

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings It won't be easy, which is why it's important to have all those warnings turned on.